# Enable-PSRemoting with wmic command won't work

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I try to enable psremoting on a remote pc with wmic command on the local machine.

```
wmic /node:"ip" /user:admin process call create "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\netshare\EnablePSRemote.ps1"
```

EnaplePSRemoting Script contains the Following:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
Restart-Service WinRM
```

I am getting following error message:

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig : Access is denied.
```

If I login to the remote pc with mstsc and execute the script on the remote pc, it says:

```
WinRM has been updated to receive requests.
WinRM service type changed successfully.
WinRM service started.
Configured LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotel
y to local users.

WinRM has been updated for remote management.
Created a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on thi
s machine.


WinRM Security Configuration.
This command modifies the TrustedHosts list for the WinRM client. The computers
 in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. The client might send
credential information to these computers. Are you sure that you want to modify
 this list?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

If I confirm with yes it return successful and I can login without any problems with my remote powershell.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied

Comment: my machine is listed under public network. I am using powershell v2 and tried to set it to private via registry change (in powershell). but with no luck, its still saying access denied. and as I posted it works if I run the script locally.